# Integration Tests in grails: getting null in query string parameter

Tags: grails, request.querystring, integration-testing

I'm doing integration tests  for controllers in grails.I need to pass query string in test case and I'm passing it as `controller.request.queryString` for the same.

My tests is getting failed. It's giving me `null value` for the query String parameter.

Controller - UserExController

Foll is the action on which i'm doing integration testing.In this I'm reading query string parameter 'uid' and getting the userInstance using GORM method

```
def getUser() {
    //reading the query string parameter 'uid'
    def userId = request.getParameter("uid")  
    User user = User.findByUsername(userId)
    render view:'edit', model:[userInstance:user]
}
```

This is the test for the above written action .In this I'm passing the query string parameter and calling the action

```
class UserInstanceTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    void testPerfSummaryApi() {
        def userExController=new UserExController()
        userExController.request.queryString='uid=rp123'
        userExController.getUser()
        def model = userExController.modelAndView.model.userInstance
        assertNotNull model
    }
}
```

I'm getting `groovy.lang.MissingMethod.Exception` in the foll call:

```
User.findByUsername(userId) //userId is comming null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in Controller:

```
def userId = request.getParameter("uid")
```

to

```
def userId = params.uid
```

Change in int test:

```
userExController.request.queryString='uid=rp123'
```

to

```
userExController.params.uid='rp123'
```

Grails' dynamic binding helps in binding the query parameters to `params` and request to `request` in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but changing userExController.request.queryString='uid=rp123' to userExController.params.uid='rp123' does not change anything. error persists. Why make changes to the controller as the controller code is working fine. I dont think there is need to change already running code to make integration tests work.

Answer (score 0):

This should make things work for you (tested on Grails 2.0.4):

```
 userExController.request.addParameter('uid', 'rp123')
```

However, I would recommend to turn to dmahapatro's suggestion and refactor your controller to use `params.uid` instead of `request.getParameter("uid")`. Or even introduce a command object.   The way you are doing it now just does not seem to be the standard Grails way.